# Vue.js で TypeError:formatDate is not a function が出てしまう

Tags: vue.js, firebase

Vue.js、Buefy、firebaseを使いwebアプリを作成しております。
フォームに入力した情報をボタンをクリックして＠clickイベントを実行しpublishを実行しています。
その際、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
恐らくショボいミスなのでしょうが、ご享受お願いします。

#### エラー

```
TypeError:formatDate is not a function
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: formatDate is not a function"
found in
---> <BButton>
<Create> at src/views/Create.vue
<App> at src/App.vue
<Root>
```

#### 試したこと

`const date = this.$date(new Date(), "DD MMMM, YYYY")` を
`const date = this.$date(new Date(), "dd MMMM, yyyy")` に変えてみる。
`` const date = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(`2020/01/01 00:00:00`)); `` に変えてみたりしましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

#### 現状のソースコード

```
<section>
    <h2 class="title is-3">taitle</h2>
         <b-input type="text" class="new_input" placeholder="Title" v-model="title"></b-input>

         <b-input type="text" class="tag" placeholder="タグ" v-model="tag" @keypress.enter="addTag"></b-input>
        <div v-if="tags.length > 0" class="tags">
          <li v-for="(tag,idx) in tags" :key="idx" class="content is-rounded">
           {{ tag }}
           <span class="cursor-pointer" @click="removeTag"></span>
          </li>
        </div>
        <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Content" v-model="content"></textarea>
      <b-button type="is-primary" @click="publish" expanded>投稿する</b-button>
  </section>
    
    <script>
    import firebase from 'firebase';
    import { auth } from '@/main'
    import { db } from '@/main'
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          title: '',
          tags: [],
          content: '',
          tag: '',
          currentUser: {}
        }
      },
      created() {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => { 
          this.currentUser = user
        })
      },
      methods: {
        addTag() {
          this.tags.push(this.tag),
          this.tag = ''
        },
        removeTag(idx) {
          this.tags.splice(idx,1)
        },
        publish() {
          const date = this.$date(new Date(), "dd MMMM, yyyy")
          db.collection('posts').add({
            title: this.title,
            tags: this.tags,
            content: this.content,
            createdAt: date,
            uid: this.currentUser.uid
          })
          .then((post) =>
            this.$router.push('/post/' + this.post.uid + '/' + this.post.id),
            alert('The post got published!')
          )
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/270720

Answer (score 1):

`this.$date`とされてるのは何か意味があるのでしょうか。
Vueのプロパティにはdateはないと思いますが（dataならありますけど）

独自にdateを別で定義されてないかぎり、そもそも存在していないのでアクセスできないと思います。

またJS単体だとDateをそのようにフォーマットする組み込み関数自体がないのではと思います。

どこからかコードを持ってこられたのでしょうか？？

JSは日付操作時が若干貧弱なので、一般的にはmomentjsなどを使って実装することが多いです。

ターミナルで

```
npm install moment
```

もしくは

```
yarn add moment
```

した後

```
import moment from 'moment'
 //（中略）
const date = moment().format('dd MMMM, yyyy')
```

で通るのではと思います。

Comment: 補足ですが、ちなみにご参考にされたコードもどこかでVueのメソッドとしてmomentjsを噛ませている可能性大です。

`
import moment from moment
Vue.prototype.$date = moment
`

に類するコードが別の場所にあり、それで
`
this.$date
`
が使えてるのだと思います。
上述の通り、JSだけだと日付操作が難しいので、元から自作プラグインやグローバルメソッドとして、momentjsを噛ませてVueで利用できるようにされる方も多いです。